# Solr error while indexing using post.jar

Tags: xml, solr, indexing, schema, ioexception

Hiee,

I am using solr to index some xml files. 
My xml file looks like:

```
<add>
<doc>
  <field name="id">736</field>
  <field name="title">President of China lunches with Brazilian President</field>
  <field name="date">November 13, 2004</field>
  <field name="content"> Data comes here </field>
  <field name="location">Brazil</field>
  <field name="coords">43.17614,-90.57341</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

My schema.xml has the following fields:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="location" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="coords" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

When I use POST to index the file I get the following error:

```
C:\Apache\solr-4.5.1\example\solr\collection1\data>java -jar post.jar 1.xml
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type a
pplication/xml..
POSTing file 1.xml
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException
: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/up
date
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
Time spent: 0:00:00.034
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey I checked the server side log and realized that the data field type date, dint support the format of date I provided, hence the error!

Answer (score 3):

when you post to solr you need to specify the collection you are updating e.g. `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update`.

example:
`java -Dauto -Durl="http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update" -jar post.jar ~/foo/bar/baz.csv`

you also need an solr.xml (on the dir where the cores are) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solr> 
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
        <core name = "collection1" instanceDir="collection1"/>
    </cores>

    <queryResultWindowSize>100</queryResultWindowSize>
</solr>
```

you can also have solrconfig.xml in the same directory with schema.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_43</luceneMatchVersion>
  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false">
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
  </requestDispatcher>
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/admin" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />
</config>
```